# Adding a tooltip to a IXLCell in a IXLWorksheet

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015, openxml

What is the syntax to add a tooltip to a IXLCell in a IXLWorksheet?
I'm trying this approach but it isn't working..........

```
    Dim xlDoc As New XLWorkbook()
    xlDoc.AddWorksheet(filename)
    Dim xlWS As IXLWorksheet = xlDoc.Worksheets(0)
    xlWS.Range("A1", "I177").Style.Font.SetFontName("Arial")
    xlWS.Range("A1", "I177").Style.Font.SetFontSize(10)
    xlWS.Range("A1", "I177").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromArgb(253, 233, 217)
    xlWS.Protect().SetSelectLockedCells(False)
    Dim rowInt As Integer = 5
    While rowInt <= 177
        xlWS.Rows(rowInt).Height = 14.25
        xlWS.Rows(rowInt).Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center)
        rowInt = rowInt + 1
    End While


xlWS.Cell("H30").Hyperlink.Tooltip = "Tooltip text string goes here"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but there's probably a more elegant way of doing it like wrapping the comment box size rather than setting the dimensions manually

```
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.Style.Size.SetHeight(50)
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.Style.Size.SetWidth(50)
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.AddText("Tooltip text 1")
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.AddNewLine()
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.AddNewLine()
    xlWS.Cell("H30").Comment.AddText("Tooltip text 2").Bold = True
```